# Having trouble aligning the text boxes vertically for user input in Java

Tags: java, swing, alignment

I'm new to Java and having trouble aligning the text boxes vertically..

This is what's showing up right now:

[image]

I have tried changing the myPanel.add(Box.createVerticalBox());, but it's still showing up horizontally.

Here's my code:

```
import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class gui_test {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      JTextField xField = new JTextField(10);
      JTextField yField = new JTextField(10);

      JPanel myPanel = new JPanel();
      myPanel.add(new JLabel("x:"));
      myPanel.add(xField);
      myPanel.add(Box.createVerticalBox()); // a spacer
      myPanel.add(new JLabel("y:"));
      myPanel.add(yField);

      int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, myPanel, 
               "Please Enter X and Y Values", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
      if (result == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
         System.out.println("x value: " + xField.getText());
         System.out.println("y value: " + yField.getText());
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Note that putting a VerticalBox in your JPanel won't help at all, since you're not changing the layout manager which is what is in control of the placement of components.  Consider using a GridLayout, GridBagLayout, or BoxLayout as all could work in this situation, and your best bet is to learn about and experiment with the various layouts.  You can find the layout manager tutorial here: [Layout Manager Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)

Comment: Myself, I'd use a GridBagLayout, but for simple GUI's a GridLayout could work if you put your JLabel and JTextArea into a JPanel (that by default uses FlowLayout), and then add those panels into the GridLayout using JPanel.